# Help understanding letter sets

Tags: phonetics, computational-linguistics, speech-synthesis

I am trying to understand the working of an old computer speech synthesizer (SAM for the commodore64) which uses a series of rules to break English text into a string of phonemes.  The rules make some frequent tests for membership of the following letter sets:

```
//  0x04        [ D J L N ]
//  0x08        [ B D G J L M N R V W Z ]
//  0x10        [ C G J S X Z R S T Z ]
```

Is anyone able to spot what traits the following sets may have and why they are significant?

Would I be correct in thinking the 0x10 set are fricatives?

Thanks in advance for any insight you can provide.

Comment: What are these? Letters typed in English? Codes for individual phonemes? How does the synthesizer work? What's the input like?

Comment: Since it was said that the code is there breaks English text into phonemes and to sort letters into groups, I suppose these are actual letters rather than symbols encoding phonemes.

Comment: For all letters, there are associated 'flags' which denote that the letter belongs to a specific set (the meaning of each set is what I aim to deduce.)  One letter can belong to multiple sets.  So above, the letters D,J,L and N all belong to one set, which the computer marks with the number 0x04.

As an example, here is a rule defined by the system:
```
'.(S) =Z'
```

Comment: If the rule on the left hand side of the = is matched then the Phoneme encoded in text on the right hand will be output.  As best I can see, the '.' here will match any of the characters in set 0x08.  The ' ' character on the right hand side of the parenthesis will match against any letter at all.  The rule as a whole will match any letters in set 0x08 if they are followed by a 'S' character and any other alpha character.

I'm not sure if that will clear anything up, but hopefully is shows a little more of the context for this question.

Comment: This resembles regexp methods of decomposing segments into features, without particular concern for phonetics. There must be more that just 3 such sets: the "meaning" of the sets would emerge from looking at what all of the sets are, e.g. what other sets is "D" a member of? "R" is in x'08, x'10, "L" is in x'04, x'08, so inferring the "meaning" would require having the total list.

Comment: I don’t know what references you’ve already used, but some of the comments suggest that these would be interesting to the group, at least: http://www.retrobits.net/atari/sam.shtml and http://simulationcorner.net/index.php?page=sam . The system appears to consist of a large set of spelling-to-phoneme rules, which then uses a version of ARPABET. I don’t see the reason for the strange groupings, either, but they must be letters, not phonemes. But, if you already have letter-to-phone rules, why would you need groupings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get the full pattern, but there are some common properties:

- `D` [d], `L` [l], `N` [n] are all voiced [alveolar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alveolar_consonant)
  consonants; `J`    (usually pronounced [dʒ]) is     [postalveolar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postalveolar_consonant)
- `[ B D G J L M N R V W Z ]` are all [voiced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_(phonetics)); `[ J L M N R V W Z ]` are also
  [sonorants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonorant), but `[ B D G ]`
  are not
- `C`(when pronounced [s]), `G` (when pronounced [dʒ]), `J` ([dʒ]) `S` ([s] or [ʃ] in "sh"), `X` ([ks]) `Z` ([z]) are
  [sibilants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sibilant); however `G` when
  pronounced [g], `C` when pronounced [k] and `R` ([ɹ], or [ɻ],),
  `T` ([t]) don't quite fit in there and I don't know why `S` and `Z`
  occur twice in the row.
  They are not all frictavices since [t] is a [plosive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_consonant), [dʒ] is an [affricacte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affricate_consonant), [ks] is a velar plosive + alveolar fricative, and [ɹ], [ɻ] are [approximants](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/approximant)

Comment: This is a really nice insight and exactly what I was looking for, very interesting :)